# can I describe AWS::ApiGateway::Model schema in yaml format

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway

I have api-gateway cloudFormation template, and I have AWS::ApiGateway::Model:

```
Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Model
Properties:
  ContentType: String
  Description: "OsRules model desc"
  Name: OsRule
  RestApiId: !Ref Segment
  Schema: json
```

I have a question, can I describe `Schema` key in yaml format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, see [the following example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigateway-model.html#YAML) in the documentation:

```
PetsModelNoFlatten:
  Type: 'AWS::ApiGateway::Model'
  Properties:
    RestApiId: !Ref RestApi
    ContentType: application/json
    Description: Schema for Pets example
    Name: PetsModelNoFlatten
    Schema:
      $schema: 'http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#'
      title: PetsModelNoFlatten
      type: array
      items:
        type: object
        properties:
          number:
            type: integer
          class:
            type: string
          salesPrice:
            type: number
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Have you looked at the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigateway-model.html#cfn-apigateway-model-schema)? Amazon has an example on page of the formatting...

```
Schema:
  $schema: 'http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#'
  title: PetsModelNoFlatten
  type: array
  items:
    type: object
    properties:
      number:
        type: integer
      class:
        type: string
      salesPrice:
        type: number
```